# Recover DHCP lease if it has been lost

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan

So my system lost it's DHCPv4 lease. Since this is the WAN uplink, the system then became unreachable. I can't see any trace that it has tried to recovery from this.

Apr  3 00:31:47 mistik systemd-networkd[1519076]: vlan20: DHCP lease lost
Apr  3 00:31:47 mistik systemd-networkd[1519076]: vlan20: DHCPv4 address x.x.x.x/24 via x.x.x.1

In RedHat you have "PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT" that can be set in the interface configuration files, if you *don't* set it, it will retry forever (I think).

How do I instruct netplan to retry forever?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; but do mention an off-topic system, so why ask here? Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic and clarify why you're asking here.

Comment: Have you tried restarting networking?